# DateTime format in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, format

how can I format datetime in php from: *Tue Dec 09 2014 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)* to: *2014-12-09 12:00*?

Thank you.

**Problem solved. I did it by myself:**

```
$datep = $_POST["datetimepicker"];
$placeholders = array('(FLE', 'Standard', 'Time)');
$vals = array('', '', '');
$str = str_replace($placeholders, $vals, $datep);
$newDate = date('Y/m/d H:i', strtotime($str));
echo $newDate;
```

Comment: You need to look at the documentation for PHP. Do you know where to find it? =]

Comment: I'm not as dumb as you think :)

Comment: The reason people have downvoted your question is because you didn't explain what you had tried so far, or explain you've looked at the docs but still didn't understand. If you don't fully explain yourself, people will think you genuinly don't know where the docs are =p

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use the datetime class:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime($yourDateTimeVariable);
$dateTime = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i');
echo $dateTime;
```

Comment: By adding my variable it shows current time not my variable.

Comment: Can you copy/paste the code you have right now?

Comment: Is there possible to post variable using POST method?

Comment: Yes sure of course you can.

Comment: $dateTime = new DateTime('".$_POST["datetimepicker"]."');
$dateTime = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i');
echo $dateTime;

Something like this?

Comment: Change: `new DateTime('".$_POST["datetimepicker"]."');` to: `new DateTime($_POST["datetimepicker"]);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66394/discussion-between-xinel-and-daan).

Comment: All I get is: Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object.

Comment: Which php version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$date = "Tue Dec 09 2014 12:00:00 GMT+0200";
$newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: $datep = $_POST["datetimepicker3"];
$newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($datep));
echo $newDate;

And I get: Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object.

Comment: You are using a method named `format()`. check that out.

Comment: Okay, now I get: 1970-01-01 03:00, but it should be 2014-12-08 14:20

Comment: it might be because of the format of date. Please check for valid date formats.

Comment: I already solved the problem, check the first post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strototime` combined with `date`. Something like

```
$date = "Tue Dec 09 2014 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)";

$format = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($date));
```